# How to use assembly to draw graphics in linux terminal?

Tags: assembly, x86, ncurses, att, gnu-assembler

**notice: I mean LINUX TERMINAL, rather than MS-DOS.**

In `MS-DOS`, I remember I can use `int 10h` to draw graphics. But I don't know how to draw graphics in modern os, it has protected mode, so I can't straight access `video Memory`.

Because I am confituring vim again recently, and I notice some of plugins, espicially like [dashboard](https://github.com/glepnir/dashboard-nvim), it can draw graphics. hmm, In some cases, I resize the window(I remote connect linux, so it is a terminal emulator), and plugins can adapt to screen size.

I writed some asm codes, such as, I allocated hundreds of bytes in `data section`, and filled some characters(like 0, 1, 2), then iterator `data section` and accoding to the  `0, 1, 2` to splicing string, for example, I matched the `0`, so I generated `"="`. finally, I call `syscall` to output above splicing string.

I write some pseudocode to explain above.

```
  int arr[..] = {0, 1, 2};
  char bss[...];

  for(int i = 0; i < ...; i ++) {
    if(arr[i] = 0) {
      bss[i] = '=';
    } else if(arr[i] = 1) {
      bss[i] = '*';
    }
    ...
  }

  printf("%s", bss);
```

I don't think the asm code I wrote is convenient, such as, I can't get the specifc coordinate(like x, y), and If I wanna fill the whole window, but I don't know the width and height of the window. etc.I know `escape sequences` can manipulate the screen position, I'm not sure if I need to encapsulation it(mean create a function, and pass parameter).

I know [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html),  it's amazing. I don't know if I can do some simple apis using gnu assembly, like get window width, get cursor location, get coordinate. etc.

Comment: Now, I know `ioctl TIOCSWINSZ` can get window size!

Comment: `ncurses` is a library.  You can call library functions from asm, if you want, if you link your program with it.  Otherwise you can write asm that makes the same system calls (read/write/ioctl) that ncurses functions would have made.